# How to set focus to an input element (searchbox) on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I wonder how to set the focus to an input field on the mouseover event.

I wonder how to onload input field or onfocus field for typing when onmouseover to it so it easily ready to type when cursor touching or onmouseover cursor to input field of search box.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`focus()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) method to focus an HTML element. Here's an example of its usage:

```
var inputField = document.getElementById('idOfYourInputField');

inputField.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    inputField.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.input-element').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).focus();
})
```

Or if you want to control the focus and blur events

```
$('.input-element')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).focus();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).blur();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting here but if you want something like at certain position on page if user moves mouse you want the textbox to get Focus you can do something like:

```
<div id='d1'>
<input type='text' id='txt' value='Search'/>
</div>
```

and with Jquery:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('#d1').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).children().closest('Input[type=text]').focus();
  });
});
```